# Thread in Android and crash

Tags: java, android, multithreading, crash, runnable

I would call a simple thread in my class but when i call it the application crash. this is the Thread:

```
private void startGame() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (isGiocoAttivo()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(velocitaDiGioco);
                    accendiBomba();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

How can i solve it? The method accendiBomba:

```
private void accendiBomba() {
    try {
        do {
            this.x = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (righe - 1));
            this.y = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (colonne - 1));
        } while (!this.action(this.x, this.y));
    } catch (CampoException ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some logs from your logcat? Are you performing any UI operation in your method accendiBomba();?

Comment: post the code of `accendiBomba()` method. guess updating ui from thread.

Comment: logcat: can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

Comment: @user2520969 you are updating ui from backgroudn thread which is not possible use `runOnUiThread` to update ui.

Comment: Great!! i use runOnUIThread instead of Thread!

Comment: No.  `runOnUiThread` is for updating ui . if you want to do back ground computation that can be done in the thread. use `runOnUiThread` iniside the thread if you need to update ui.

Comment: I must change icon of imageButton, so i must use ronOnUIThread, right? What method can i use to change icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following within your thread

```
private void startGame() {
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (isGiocoAttivo()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(velocitaDiGioco);
               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    accendiBomba() 
                }
            });
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }

    }
}).start();}
```